# Serverless Framework with Node MySQL: PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE error

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm having difficulties implementing a simple query on a AWS Lambda NodeJS (with Serverless Framework). Running it locally works, but when I upload it to AWS and then try to run it using the API Gateway endpoint, I get this error:

```
{
    "code": "PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE",
    "fatal": true
}
```

I can't find any information on Google, StackOverflow or GitHub about this error, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I'm trying.

```js
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host : '', 
        user : '', 
        password : '', 
        database : ''
    });

    function getLists (client_id,api_key,callback){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE client_id = ?",
        [client_id],function(error, results){
            connection.end();
            callback(error,results);
        }
    )};

    module.exports.run = function(event, context, cb) {
        getLists(event.x_mail_list_client_id,'',function(error,results){
            if(error){
                return cb(null,error);
            }
            return cb(null,results);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit awsm.json.

```
"exclude": [
  "aws-sdk",
  "mysql"
],
"includePaths": [
  "node_modules/mysql",
  "node_modules/bignumber.js",
  "node_modules/readable-stream",
  "node_modules/isarray",
  "node_modules/core-util-is",
  "node_modules/inherits",
  "node_modules/string_decoder"
]
```

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1249

Comment: I solved it few weeks ago, but I forgot that this question still open, it's the right answer, thank you =)

Answer (score 3):

In general the problem you encounter is the disability of the serverless-optimizer-plugin to handle dynamically loaded NPM modules or globals correctly (e.g. when using the mysql NPM package). So you have to exclude it from optimization.
The solution heavily depends on the serverless version and the Node version you use, so I will list the different solutions below:

**Severless v4 + Node v4**:

Set the excludes in your `s-component.json` as follows:

```
"custom": {
  "optimize": {
    "exclude": [
      "aws-sdk",
      "mysql"
    ],
    "includePaths": [
      "node_modules/mysql"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Serverless v5 + Node v4**:
Components have been obsoleted and removed in this serverless version favoring functions instead. So apply the optimizer configuration directly to your `s-function.json` configuration files.

**Node v5**:
The NPM executable included with Node v5 internally does dependency optimization and dependency module flattening. This is not yet really compatible with the current serverless-optimizer-plugin. The solution here is to add the dependencies that are already optimized by NPM as proposed by @Masatsugu Hosoi in his answer above like this

```
"custom": {
  "optimize": {
    "exclude": [
      "aws-sdk",
      "mysql"
    ],
    "includePaths": [
      "node_modules/mysql",
      "node_modules/bignumber.js",
      "node_modules/readable-stream",
      "node_modules/isarray",
      "node_modules/core-util-is",
      "node_modules/inherits",
      "node_modules/string_decoder"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For any coming in the future**

what worked for me to add the following in the **webpack.config.js** file

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false
}
```

Mysql does not seem to like the minification

Comment: thanks. this works well. I am using ERB, electron react boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exactly same problem.

The problem is with the browserify and the mysql module. Unfortunately I couldn't find a real solution.

By reading the code the browserify is the only available option as builder.

https://github.com/jaws-framework/JAWS/blob/master/lib/commands/deploy_lambda.js

You can set the 'builder' as false. This will simply zip all your files before sending them to Amazon.

Unfortunately (again) just doing this will not work. For some reason all files are inside a 'node_module' folder to work you must take the files out before upload the package.

Still, all this is manual...

edit: There is already an open issue about this last part:
https://github.com/jaws-framework/JAWS/issues/239

Comment: I was just realizing it when you answer my post, so, I hope that we can find a solution, or wait for a pull request that fix this problem.

Comment: Hi Pedro. It's nice to find somebody else with the same problem (or it isn't lol). This is my issue on the node mysql repo: github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1249